# intent-filter in the manifest does not launch my activity

Tags: android, android-manifest, intentfilter

I'm doing a "new app" within the Settings app that manages Bluetooth. I have the next problem: I want my activity to be launched when the next android intent is sent by the framework: android.bluetooth.device.action.PAIRING_REQUEST

Due to this, I added this to the AndroidManifest.xml in the Settings app:

```
<activity android:name=".mybt.MyBluetoohSettings">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.PAIRING_REQUEST" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The problems is that, once that intent is sent by the framework.... my app is not launched!

I've also tried it using just a single intent-filter (with MAIN & PAIRING_REQUEST intents)

In theory this should work, right? What am I doing wrong? Suggestions?

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

The Bluetooth pairing request needs to be handled by a Receiver (extended from BroadcastReceiver) rather than an Activity.  Your manifest should therefore contain an element, inside `<application>`, that looks something like this :

```
    <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.PAIRING_REQUEST" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And somewhere in your application, you'll have a class called MyReceiver :

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

      //
      // Handle the pairing request
      //
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've seen that in the original Bluetooth app. But I don't understand why they do that. Why can't use an activity instead? Could you explain it?
My problems is that right now, my activity has a broadcast receiver object with an intent filter. So when my activity is instantiated, the receiver is registered and I can process the intents. But, if it is not... i want android to launch it. Any suggestion for this architecture?
Thanks!

Comment: It's just the nature of broadcasting within Android; because there may be multiple applications interested in the pairing request, a Broadcast Receiver is used.  The behavior should be the same, though; if you have a Broadcast Receiver registered in your manifest, Android will start up your application and invoke the BroadcastReceiver when the event occurs, even if the app isn't running at the time. Note that this will not work if the app has crashed or been forced closed; if this is the desired behavior you'll need to create a sticky Service that Android will attempt to restart.